# Pass jquery variable to img src static in Django template

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I am getting a list of file names (they are .jpg images) from a django view as an Ajax response. I want to append each image to a div (with id grid). Below is the code:

```js
success: function(response) {
  var state = response.state;
  var piclist = response.pics.toString();
  var pics = piclist.split(',');
  // alert(pics);

  for (var i = 0; i < pics.length; i++) {
    // alert(pics[i]);
    // var fname = state + '/' + pics[i];
    // var fpath = "{% static '" + fname + "' %}";
    // alert(fpath);

    $('#grid').append(
      "<div class='col-md-2 mb-2 posr'>" +
      "<input type='checkbox' class='custom-control-input chk pos-ab'>" +
      "<img src='{%static fpath %}' class='img-thumbnail'>" +
      "</div>"
    );
  }
}
```

I am unable to pass the file path variable `ts/pics[i]` to img src static. I tried Jquery template literals too but that also didnt work. How to pass the filepath variable?

Using template literal and placeholder is also not working:

```html
<div class='col-md-2 mb-2 posr'>\
  <input type='checkbox' class='custom-control-input chk pos-ab'>\
  <img src={% static ${fname} %} class='img-thumbnail'>\
</div>
```

Browser is interpreting `fname` as is and not taking it as a variable.

Comment: Can i see your ajax view from backend ? You can send the full path including static location from views.py (From backend)

Comment: @ShiBilPK Thanks but I solved this. Posted answer.

Comment: I had posted the answer but I dont know why some moderator as deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var fpath = `{% static '' %}` + fname;
```

```
   $('#grid').append(
      "<div class='col-md-2 mb-2 posr'>" +
      "<input type='checkbox' class='custom-control-input chk pos-ab'>" +
      `<img src="${fpath}" class='img-thumbnail'>` +
      "</div>"
    );
```

Comment: I solved this.

In place of:

<img src="{% static '${fname}' %}" class='img-thumbnail'>
Use this:

<img src="static/${fname}" class='img-thumbnail'>

Comment: In that case, if you change static url in settings.py that not effect here.